# Is it accurate to say "I will mostly pass on something"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Here's a conversation that I had with a friend

`Him: Do you want to come to the store with me today after work?`

`Me: I will mostly pass`

I wanted to express that it's not very likely that I will join him with my sentence. I was wondering if this sentence violates the rules of grammar, or sounds strange in general?

A friend says that it can *only* be used for recurring actions or situations where my choice can be repeated, such as "Given the choice of beer vs wine, I will mostly take beer", but not for a one-time thing such as above example.

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer the question of whether you're going, does it? Only the question of how much you **want** to go. Probly your friend just wants a straight answer. Note, by the way, that this is ambiguous in writing; the _pass_ has to be stressed, rather than the _on_; the serial verb _pass on_ refers to inheritance, among other things.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the assertiveness/directness of the answer, but rather the mechanics/grammar of it.

Comment: That's not only inaccurate… it's also clearly impossible.
If you could "mostly" pass on that, what would your other part do, and how, please?

What choice would "I will mostly pass" leave the lesser part of you to do?

If you’re really asking about the meaning of “(A large) part of me/I mostly/on the one hand… want(s) to” that’s a very different Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not grammatically correct. You cannot "mostly pass" on a single action. You can only "pass" on it. Your answer, if you did not want to go to the store, ought to have been:

"I will pass."

If you are unsure about whether you will go to the store, but probably will not, you might say, "I will likely pass".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this also mean that when asked `What will you choose, given a choice between a beer and a wine?`, `I will mostly take beer.` would be incorrect as well?

Comment: You certainly can "mostly pass" on a single action. This has nothing to do with grammar, as the sentence is certainly grammatical. Grammatical constructions don't have to make sense, remember.

Comment: @Robusto I disagree. Although, to be fair, it's not correct to talk about single or non-single action. It's about having something in a group, where "mostly" refers to something that occurs for majority of that group. It can be time-based (I mostly drink red wine) or object based (laptops are mostly black). Even Merriam-Webster defines it as "for the most part", synonym of "mainly". How can you say "Are you coming with us in 15 mins? I will mostly pass". It would only make sense if a major part of you is coming with them, say, your upper body and your right leg. "Most likely" yes, "mostly" no.

Comment: @Robusto Unless you meant to say that it obeys the grammar of English language in terms of positioning the right types of words in the right places in the sentence. In that sense, I agree. "I will mostly pass" is grammatically correct, while "I pass mostly will" isn't. But I guess we do agree that it's an improper use of word "mostly" given its formal definition and meaning, which is what the question is about. Main proof for it being grammatically correct is the fact that there is a context where it's OK, e.g. "What will you do given a choice x vs y? I will mostly pass".

Comment: In case you guys were wondering, @slouc is my obnoxious friend.

Comment: @slouc: That's what I did say. That's what grammar is.

Comment: @Robusto Main discussion was whether or not "I will mostly pass" is a viable answer to a question "We are leaving in 15 mins, are you coming with us?". It's an incorrect usage in this particular example, but I don't know what's the word for that situation in English. It's just as wrong as saying "My cat likes it's food", because correct saying would be "My cat likes its food", but former isn't grammatically incorrect. Cat might indeed like the fact that it has been magically turned into food.

Comment: I also don't agree that using *mostly* there is improper. In need of an explanation, perhaps, but not impossible to mean something real by it. For example, if you asked me to go to the beach to swim and play beach volleyball, I might "mostly pass" in that I would go to the beach with you but not swim or play volleyball.

Comment: @Robusto I agree that the volleyball example is correct. It's about the group of activities, out of which you will partake in majority of. Example in the original question was literally "Are you joining us after work today? I will mostly pass". "I will mostly pass" is identical to "I will pass most of it" or "Majority of me will pass", neither of which makes sense as an answer here (you either join or you don't, and you can't have a part of you join and part not). Your beach example works fine with "I will pass most of it" though.

Comment: "I will mostly pass" is *syntactically* correct but *semantically* wrong. The problem with using the word *grammar* (as I've learned) is that it has two different senses: one is for usage, the other is for syntax. People who use a different sense than you do get confused or upset. I only say *grammatical* or *ungrammatical* when something succeeds or fails on both points—otherwise, I specify.

Comment: @KarthikIyengar I haven't seen anybody answer your beer question, so I will try. "I will mostly drink beer" would be intuitive to mean "I will have multiple drinks, and most of them will be beer" because "mostly" references proportion. If you're instead talking about a single thing that *might* happen then you need a word that references "likeliness" instead, such as "probably".